# There is an error in XML document (2, 2).What does this mean?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to read XML document.
My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SplashScreen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Path>SplashScreen/Image-King</Path>
</SplashScreen>
```

My code which is reading XML:

```
XmlGameScreen = new XmlManager<GameScreen>();
XmlGameScreen.Type = currentscreen.Type;
currentscreen = XmlGameScreen.Load("LoadXML/SplashScreen.xml");
```

And

```
public Type Type;
public T Load(string path)
{
    T instance;
    using (TextReader textreader = new StreamReader(path))
    {

        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(Type);
        instance = (T)xml.Deserialize(textreader);
    }
    return instance; 
}
```

I am getting error on `instance = (T)xml.Deserialize(textreader);` Is my XML document wrong? I am trying to read `<Path>`.
Update :
My Internal Exception:
Cannot serialize member `'MyRPGgame.SplashScreen._image'` of type `'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D'`

Comment: I think (2, 2) means the error is in line 2, column 2.  But the XML document looks OK.  Are you sure you aren't loading something else?

Comment: No only this xml document...

Comment: Add a line of code (textreader.ReadToEnd()) to put the output of the text reader into a string and use the debugger to examine it.  (As a sanity check).

Comment: Problem is your instantiating an `XmlManager` of type `GameScreen` but trying to load an XML file with type `SplashScreen` in it. Maybe. I'm not sure because I do not understand the semantic difference between `T` and `Type` in your code. Perhaps showing those two extra types would be helpful. This code works for me if `SplashScreen` is a subclass of `GameScreen`.

Comment: yes SplashScreen is a subclass of GameScreen

Comment: Just as a side note to fellow readers in the future: after a while struggling with these issues I decided to switch to JSON. If you a can do so in your project as well and it suits your interests just three words: go for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My experience from it would be that in the 2nd line in the 2nd chararacter, there is an error.
have a look if your class names are different from the XML tags. are you maybe changing the "XML Root name" to a different one.

Have a look at the XML structure and which class are you serializing to which node.

Also, read the 
[MSDN Documentation about the XmlRootAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: From my experience, this error means that the root element has another Tag name than expected. The actual tag name begins on line 2, character 2.

Answer (score 33):

In my case it appears one of the Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 updates caused this error when trying to open SSRS projects. The solution is to delete the *.rptproj.rsuser file from the project folder and try again.

Comment: also try deleting any `*.suo` files

Comment: I didn't have an rsuser file as the project was coming from TFS. So I created a new SSRS project, found the differences in it vs the project I could not open (which were just XML namespaces), changed the project I couldn't open, and then opened that project.

Comment: I've tried delete some files as this answer suggest. A workaround which works for me was create a new SSRS project, then add all existent elements.

Comment: I deleted both *.rptproj.ruser and *.rptproj.user and this fixed the issue for me. I had the same issue as @user875318, trying to open an SSRS solution in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.7.

Comment: I had the same issue, when I tried to open (by mistake) solution from VS2015 instead of VS2017.

Comment: @YuryKozlov - sounds like in other words, you had a 2017 project, but were trying to open it in VS 2015 and thus an error. That was how I got this error (someone upgraded it from 2015 to 2017 without telling others).

Comment: @mmcrae exactly

Answer (score 4):

That usually means you have whitespace at the start of the file; check for a line-break before the `<?xml...`. Even better: please show the first few bytes (preferably as far as `<SplashScreen`) of the file as viewed in a binary editor.

It *could* also mean you have an invisible unicode or control character somewhere before the `<SplashScreen`

Comment: I delete the .sln file and the project loaded. It looks like there was an encoding error in the sln file.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share what worked for me. I had a similar error

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 40).
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: `<tsResponse xmlns='http://xxxyyyzzzz.com/api'>` was not expected.

I was trying to deserialize a string to an object of type `tsResponse`.

After adding the following attribute `[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "tsResponse", Namespace = "http://xxxyyyzzzz.com/api")]` to the class `tsResponse` i was able to resolve my issue.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName = "tsResponse", Namespace = "http://xxxyyyzzzz.com/api")]
public class tsResponse
{
    [XmlElement]
    public CredentialsXml credentials { get; set; }
}
```

I.e had to add Namespace attribute (System.Xml.Serialization).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a property with `[XmlArrayAttribute]` had the getter accessing a field with `[XmlIgnoreAttribute]` that was left uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: When you are deserializing XML to List just add an extra
line to the start i.e  `ArrayOfAddressDirectory` as follows and don't put any space at start and end of file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfAddressDirectory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AddressDirectory>
        <Owner>MS. Dhoni</Owner>
        <Age>48</Age>
        <Company>India</Company>
    </AddressDirectory>
</ArrayOfAddressDirectory>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
namespace XmlReadProgram
{
    public class AddressDirectory
    {
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<AddressDirectory> adlist = new List<AddressDirectory>();

            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"E:\inputDirectory\address.xml"))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<AddressDirectory>));
                adlist = (List<AddressDirectory>)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
            }

           //You can use foreach to print all data

            Console.WriteLine(adlist[0].Owner);
            Console.WriteLine(adlist[0].Age);
            Console.WriteLine(adlist[0].Company);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case it's definitely the confusion between Type and template T. You are trying to construct Serializer with Type --> new XmlSerializer(Type) and then deserialize with template T ----> (T)xml.Deserialize. So the solution is to replace Type in constructing with typeof(T), and this should eliminate the initial XML document problem of (2, 2).